# Effects of dual boot on laptop

Tags: ssd

Does dual boot harms Storage Device of laptop due to partition on them. Someone says it effects SSD due to partition on them .some Some say it is good to dual-boot. Anyone has a perfect explanation of dual boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not a perfect explanation, but i’ll give it a try:

Dual-booting is having 2 operating systems on one device. You can chose which OS when your laptop/pc starts up. What is done to one, does not effect the other as they are in different disk partitions. I do not see any harm in having a dual-boot on an SSD; the only downside (that i am aware of) is the fact that neither OS has the full disk available to it. It should be fine, but be sure to give whatever OS you intend to use more a larger partition.

—Krafter